# Bootstrap 4 - col-md-offset?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Теперь только так, либо я натупил читая документацию?

```
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не до конца ознакомились с [документацией](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns). В Bootstrap 4 класс `.col-md-offset` переименован в `.offset-md`.